# Merging specific rows by summing certain columns on grouping variables

Tags: r, database, aggregate, database-management

The following dataframe is a subset of a bigger df, which contains duplicated information

```
df<-data.frame(Caught=c(92,134,92,134),
               Discarded=c(49,47,49,47),
               Units=c(170,170,220,220),
               Hours=c(72,72,72,72),
               Colour=c("red","red","red","red"))
```

In **Base R**, I would like to get the following:

```
df_result<-data.frame(Caught=226,
                      Retained=96,
                      Units=390,
                      Hours=72,
                      colour="red")
```

So basically the results is the sum of unique values for columns Caught, Retained, Units and leaving the same value for Hours and colour (Caught=92+134, Retained=49+47, Units= 170+220, Hours=72, colour="red)

However, I intend to do this in a much bigger data.frame with several columns. My idea was to apply a function based on column names as:

```
l <- lapply(df, function(x) {
  if(names(x) %in% c("Caught","Discarded","Units"))
    sum(unique(x))
  else
    unique(x)
})
as.data.frame(l)
```

However, this does not work, as I am not entirely sure how to extract vector names when using `lapply()` and other functions such as this.

I have tried withouth succes to implement `by()`, `apply()` functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Asking for Base R:

```
    l <- lapply( df, function(n) {
        if( is.numeric(n) )
            sum( unique(n) )
        else
            unique( n )
    })
    as.data.frame(l)
```

This solution takes advantage of the fact that data.frames are really just lists of vectors.

It produces this:

```
    #  Caught Discarded Units Hours Colour
    #    226        96   390    72    red
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was hoping for a less automated way of specifying which columns to sum. Instead of using as.numeric, how would I specify the columns names that I want to sum?

Comment: See the answer by baroulotte for how to explicitly handle each name in the data.frame

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the questions, as the answer from @barboulotte is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A proposition:

```
df <-data.frame(Caught=c(92,134,92,134),
                 Discarded=c(49,47,49,47),
                 Units=c(170,170,220,220),
                 Hours=c(72,72,72,72),
                 Colour=c("red","red","red","red"))

df
#>   Caught Discarded Units Hours Colour
#> 1     92        49   170    72    red
#> 2    134        47   170    72    red
#> 3     92        49   220    72    red
#> 4    134        47   220    72    red


df_results <- data.frame(Caught = sum(unique(df$Caught)),
                         Discarded = sum(unique(df$Discarded)),
                         Units = sum(unique(df$Units)),
                         Hours = unique(df$Hours),
                         Colour = unique(df$Colour))

df_results
#>   Caught Discarded Units Hours Colour
#> 1    226        96   390    72    red

# Created on 2021-02-23 by the reprex package (v0.3.0.9001)
```

Regards,